# get path of selected images from gallery using MultipleImageSelect library in android

Tags: android, path, gallery

In my project i need a way of get the path of several images selecteds from the gallery.
I´m using this library [MultipleSelectImages](https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect)

It´s apparently work fine, but in the onActivityResult i need the array with the path of each image, however the result I get is this:

```
Paths: [com.darsh.multipleimageselect.models.Image@1e6d3057, com.darsh.multipleimageselect.models.Image@33824744]
```

...when i need the real path (/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150426_110936.jpg)

Reading the doc of the library don´t found solution.

This is the onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);

        Log.i("myLogs", "Paths:" + " " + images);
    }
}
```

...Where "image" it´s imported from the library

```
import com.darsh.multipleimageselect.models.Image;
```

I´m not using EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE because need that the app works in android api 16 version

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below code;

onActivityResult();-

```
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };


            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
```

Comment: data.getData() = null :/